# Dynamically select context property?

Tags: c#, dynamic, entity-framework-6

I'm wondering if there was a way that I could reuse my code for return entities from a context dynamically. For example, I am using the following to receive all records:

```
    public List<AbandonCode> GetAbandonCodes()
    {
        List<AbandonCode> ab;
        using (DataWarehouseEntities context = new DataWarehouseEntities())
        {
            ab = (from a in context.AbandonCodes select a).ToList<AbandonCode>();
        }
        return ab;
    }
```

What im hoping to do is create a helper method similar to this but I cannot figure out how to set the `context.WhatIWantToGet` nor the return type. It would look similar to this:

```
    public List<????> GetAbandonCodes(Type t)
    {
        List<t> ab;
        using (DataWarehouseEntities context = new DataWarehouseEntities())
        {
            ab = (from a in context.???? select a).ToList<t>();
        }
        return ab;
    }
```

Is what I am trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of different options here. Here's the fully generic one using the Set< T > method on the EF context:

```
public List<T> GetAbandonCodes<T>() where T : class
{
    List<T> ab;
    using (DataWarehouseEntities context = new DataWarehouseEntities())
    {
        ab = context.Set<T>().ToList();
    }
    return ab;
}
```

... which you would call like this:

```
 var codes = GetAbandonCodes<AbandonCode>();
```

If you want to pass in a Type object, instead of calling a generic method, you can use the non-generic Set(). It's a little trickier because you'll have to cast the result to something usable:

```
    public static DbSet GetAbandonCodes(Type t)
    {
        DbSet ab;
        using (DataWarehouseEntities context = new DataWarehouseEntities ())
        {
            ab = context.Set(t);
        }
        return ab;
    }
```

You can then use it like this:

```
var codes = GetAbandonCodes(typeof(AbandonCode)).Cast<AbandonCode>().ToList();
```

I would recommend the first method, though, as it's safer and easier to use.

Comment: Aw, `Set`, nice. I should refresh my EF knowledge.